# Где ошибка в коде Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on 
it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")


class Battery():
    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            range = 240
        elif self.battery_size == 85:
            range = 270


message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
message += " miles on a full charge."
print(message)


class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()


my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

Есть вот такой код он должен выводить сообщение

> 2016 Tesla Model S
>   This car has a 70-kWh battery.
>   This car can go approximately 240 miles on a full charge.

А у меня получается вот так

> This car can go approximately  miles on a full charge.
>   2016 Tesla Model S
>   This car has a 70-kWh battery.

Вроде всё как в книге сделал где ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строки

```
message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
message += " miles on a full charge."
print(message)
```

должны быть внутри класса Battery() в функции get_range. А у вас они выползли и висят сами по себе как самостоятельный код, который и выполняется самым первым. Сдвиньте их на два уровня внутрь, чтобы было одинаково с if/elif:

```
    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            range = 240
        elif self.battery_size == 85:
            range = 270
        message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
        message += " miles on a full charge."
        print(message)
```

Comment: А что такое `range` ?

Comment: А что такое _range? Из кода очевидно, что такое range.

Comment: `range` это `<class 'range'>`, а  `_range` - это имя переменной.

Comment: range это точно такая же переменная (и даже та же  самая), которая определена парой строк выше. А вы запустили неправильный код автора и почему-то задаете мне странные вопросы о том, что он выводит. @S.Nick